# Foreach Loop is not Working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, ms-access-2007

There is problem in this code when I use parameterized query  loop get one file name in  `string filename = Path.GetFileName(item);` variable again and again

```
 string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Gallery/GalleryImage/" + newtable));


    int a = 0;

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

    OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection();

    mycon.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AGENTJ.AGENTJ-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\mfaridalam\App_Data\mfaridalam1.accdb";

    cmd = mycon.CreateCommand();

    mycon.Open();

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
    foreach (string item in filePaths)
    {
        a++;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(item);
        string ips = "00" + a.ToString();

       // Response.Write("Number (" + a.ToString() + ")    " + filename + "    " + ips + "    " + t1 + "     " + v + "     " + some + "   " + some + "<br/><br/>");

       // cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Image] ([Image],[Sort],[Created],[Albumid],[Description],[title])VALUES('" + filename + "','" + ips + "','" + dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "','" + newtable + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')";
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Image] ([Image],[Sort],[Created],[Albumid],[Description],[title])VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", filename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", ips);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", newtable);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

But when I use normal insert query

```
     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Image] ([Image],[Sort],[Created],[Albumid],[Description],[title])VALUES('" + filename + "','" + ips + "','" + dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "','" + newtable + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')";
```

loop is working alright and get all the name of files at specific location. Please let me know why ?Is there any problem in my logic ?

Comment: Why does your command text contain values of ????. I would have written the query as `cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Image] ([Image],[Sort],[Created],[Albumid],[Description],[title])VALUES (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6)";`

Comment: small correction - `... VALUES (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd.Parameters` collection is not cleared between iterations. You should create parameters before the loop and set values in the loop, instead of using `AddWithValue`

```
cmd = mycon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Image] ([Image],[Sort],[Created],[Albumid],[Description],[title])VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
cmd.Parameters.Add('@p1',...);
...same for other params...

mycon.Open();

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
foreach (string item in filePaths)
{
    a++;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(item);
    string ips = "00" + a.ToString();       

    cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = filename;
    ...same for other params...

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

However you can just add `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` :)

As it noted in MSDN

> OleDbParameterCollection.AddWithValue Method
>
> Adds a value to the end of the OleDbParameterCollection

So engine doesn't see @p1 added on the second iteration because it already found @p1 added on the first one.

Comment: i am using now cmd.Parameters.Clear(); its better :)